# Is there a way to specify the order of the result of Object.values()

Tags: javascript

I get an item from an API in the following shape :

```
data : {
    "56": { ... }, //item1
    "57": { ... }, //item2
    "58": { ... }, //item3
}
```

And I want an array of Object looking like this :

```
[
    { ... }, //item1 with key "56"
    { ... }, //item2 with key "57"
    { ... }  //item3 with key "58"
]
```

This can of course be obtained with `Object.values(data)` . But since Javascript does not guarantee the order of an object's properties, I would like to find a way to use the properties' keys to sort the result and guarantee the order of the array of object I will get. Is this doable ?

Edit : as suggested in the comments, I could use `Object.keys()`, sort the result and then use it to build my array, but I am wondering if there is a more direct and elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: You could sort the data based on the values?

Comment: Use `Object.keys()` to get the keys, sort that array however you want, and then `.map()` that onto a result array of values from the object.

Comment: you mean get `Object.keys()`, order the result, and then build the array from the result ? (Edit : as Pointy said while I was typing this comment) I could end up doing that but I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing that. I'm kind of new to javascript and am always surprised by all the little tricks available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the entries, sort them and map only the values.

```
data = Object
    .entries(object.data)
    .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
    .map(([, v]) => v)
```

Comment: I personally highly appreciate this answer! Nice!

Comment: Very close to what was proposed in the comment, but still very elegant, I like it a lot. Validating in 3 minutes when allowed, thank you !